# Ionic CLI Build Android Error: Could not find installed version of Gradle

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I am developing of android and hybrid application. Recently, I just updated of my android-sdk in my android studio. I just realize that when I build my ionic application by typing ionic build android. It display following error

```
Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

However, set ANDROID_HOME, I just pointed to recently upated Android-SDK. I have problem for me to build ionic android application before I update my application

Comment: What is the OS you are working on ?

Comment: @ChintanSoni Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Gradle doesn't work for Ionic anyhow. I wasted one full day on it.
However, I was able to solve the issue below way:

Follow manual installation guide from here : https://gradle.org/install/#manually

And once you're set with setting new gradle path to PATH variable in environment variables, you should be able to build your project.

Comment: But previously I point to android sdk also, It works for me to build and deploy my application. The problem comes only after I updated my android sdk